# Incorrect Collocation

Tags: collocations

Is this a collocation or an idiom? I found different answers online.

> To the best of my knowledge

If we change one of the words, would it be considered incorrect collocation. For example: "Answer this ON the best of YOUR knowledge."

Answer (score 6):

Some collocations give you a bit of wiggle-room.  This is one such, and you can say any phrase similar to the following:

> - to the best of *my* knowledge
> - to the best of *your* knowledge
> - to the best of *his* knowledge
> - to the best of *her* knowledge

You can't change the first few words of this collocation.  All of the following sound strange:

> - **on* the best of my knowledge
> - *to *a* best of my knowledge
> - *to the *worst* of my knowledge

However, there are related collocations which differ in only the final word:

> - to the best of my *ability*
> - to the best of my *recollection*

Note that *phrase* and *collocation* are overlapping categories, so it doesn't make sense to ask whether something fits in one category or the other.  Your example fits into both categories.

---

*In this post, I used the symbol `*` to mark phrases I find **unacceptable**.*