# Which is correct, to my knowledge. or for my knowledge.?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I was studying prepositions and stumble upon these phrases:

First

1. to my knowledge.
2. for my knowledge.

Second

1. Go for a ride
2. Go to a ride

Third

1. He went to England to a Sales Conference.
2. He went to England for a Sales Conference.

Which one from these two is correct and why?

Answer (score 1):

All of them are potentially correct depending on the context.

"To the best of my knowledge, the answer is cheese."
"And yet for all of my knowledge I was unable to answer him."

"I'm going for a ride on the bus."
"I'm going to the annual haunted hay ride."

The first one is more likely, as you'd generally go for a ride. Going to a ride would imply the ride is the final location you're heading to.

"He went to England to a Sales Conference." (He went to England, and went to the conference.)
"He went to England for a Sales Conference." (The reason he went to England is for the sales conference.)

Comment: You really should point out that both *to my knowledge* and *for my knowledge* as literally written and without any extra words with the intent to mean *to the best of my knowledge* or *as far as I know* are both [alien collocations that native speakers do not generate and may even be confused by](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/6473).